# iphone sdk button with image

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a button that has an image instead of the default look. User clicks button and chooses a photo (using image picker). I want to set the image of the photo to the photo that the user has clicked.

so, I do the following:

```
[self.activeBtn setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Unfortunately, this scales the image into the little box. What is the best way to ensure that the image is cropped by the borders of the button instead of getting scaled into it?

Edit: want to note that I'm currently on the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function to create a cropped version passing the height and width of button as arguments

```
- (UIImage*)thumbnailOfHeight:(int)height andWidth:(int)width fromImage:(UIImage*)image{
    UIImage *thumbnail;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];                                  

    BOOL isWidthGreaterThanHeight = (image.size.width > image.size.height);
    float sideFull = (isWidthGreaterThanHeight)? image.size.height : image.size.width;

    CGRect clippedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, sideFull, sideFull);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(height, width));
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextClipToRect(currentContext, clippedRect);

    CGFloat scaleFactor = width/sideFull;

    if (isWidthGreaterThanHeight) {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, -((image.size.width - sideFull)/2)*scaleFactor, 0);
    }
    else {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext,0, -((image.size.height - sideFull)/2)*scaleFactor);
    }
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

    [imageView.layer renderInContext:currentContext];
    thumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [imageView release];
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this snippet! I will have to check out this UIGraphicsContext stuff then to do some image manipulation stuff.

Comment: hmm... is there any import I need to do for CALayer? LLVM is complaining on `imageView.layer' saying that this is a forward declaration of CALayer.

Answer (score 0):

You set like

```
 [self.activeBtn setBackgroundImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: nope, I can set the background image of the button initially and that looks fine. when I set it with the above call, I just see a blank space where the image/button should be.

I'm on the simulator by the way!